# Building a JS sliding page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm developing a website for someone who requested a dynamic sliding page when you scroll (i.e. [like this](http://www.balenciaga.com/us)). At first I was thinking it was something I could use CSS transitions for, but then I realized there might be a JS tool out there which could make it work.

I discovered this [page of dynamic movement examples](http://tympanus.net/Development/PageTransitions/) with an [associated library on github](https://github.com/codrops/PageTransitions), but I'm not quite sure how to make it work. Basically, I'd like the page to listen for the event of a scroll, and then slide up a section of the page in the same way as the example above. When looking through the code for the dynamic movement examples, it seems like it's a a bunch of cases in the JS file that get used somehow in the event of a button press.

Please, if anyone is familiar with building something like this, please let me know how it might be done.

Comment: I think you forgot to add the example or didn't do so correctly as I dont see it...

Comment: try fullpage.js i`m using it right now, and i am really pleased with it

Comment: Also, take a look at http://luke.sno.wden.co.uk/full-screen-vertical-scroll

Comment: I've found [jQuery One Page Scroll](http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/onepage_scroll_demo.html) to be a highly effective solution in the past. That being said, I did have trouble  making it mobile friendly. An alternative could be [Flexslider](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/) with `direction: "vertical"`. You'd then have to detect the scroll actions on your own and make the slider move to next/prev slides manually as this is not built in to the Flexslider functionality. I _have_ however found Flexslider's responsiveness to be fairly stable.

Comment: Thank you for the responses - I forgot to add the links, have added them, but I think there are few great examples in your replies that I can make use of. Appreciate it!

Comment: I'm surprised nobody mentioned yet [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/). Compatible with touch devices and old browsers and with plenty of options, methods and callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

I would encourage you to make use of [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/).

It is nowadays the most popular library for single scrolling pages. It has plenty of options, methods and callbacks and you can almost do whatever you think of with it.

Compatible with old browsers, kinetic scrolling (Apple laptops) and touch devices.